# Delphi TCP Socket Server - broadcast/reply to multiple clients at a time

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, real-time, broadcast

*Recently I started developing simple flash (flash is limited to tcp) real time multiplayer game and I needed a server to provide communication between clients. I decided to use Delphi XE + Indy for this purpose but I found out that Indy offers the synchronous communication model. (I have never used any of the Indy components.)*

What I understood till now is that the synchronous (blocking) model limits concurrency and thus makes Indy TCP server component inappropriate for real time multiplayer game.

**My question is : Should I use non-blocking communication and what are the best tools (components,classes etc) to implement it?**

Also I will be very very happy if you provide me with example (source code) of using this tool to broadcast a message. - I want to send same message to each member of a particular "room" at once (but not send the message to other rooms' members.).

PS
Sorry for my poor english (I dont speak it natively) :)

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you need Hundreds of Thousands of active connections to a single server, I don't see any benefit to using non-blocking socket architectures. If someone comes along later who really needs that, I suggest Overbyte's ICS by Francois Piette.   However Indy can certainly handle a multi-player game server of 100, 1000 or 8000 simultaneous connections on any decent modern colocated internet server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how Indy works. Yes, it does use blocking sockets, but that does not mean it cannot be used asynchronously. The `TIdTCPServer` component is multi-threaded. It handles multiple client connections in parallel. It is certainly possible to send messages from one client to another, and to broadcast messages to multiple clients. I have posted such examples many times before on StackOverflow, the [Embarcadero forums](http://forums.embarcadero.com), and the [Indy forum](http://forums2.atozed.com). Next time, please do a little research before asking questions.

Comment: Yes, I admit I misunderstood how Indy works. However I know I could achive what i want using the LockList method but doesnt the usage of LockList prevent the execution of other threads (which I am trying to avoid)? Is there an alternative and what it is?

Comment: You're asking a question that amounts to premature optimization. Implement your server, and profile it with a performance profiler, and load test it and find real bottlenecks. No point fixing imaginary or theoretical ones yet.

Comment: LockList() prevents the execution of threads that call LockList() at the same time. Other threads are free to continue running.

Answer (score 0):

[0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) should suit you needs. 0MQ implements [PGM](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-pgm) multicasts and allow request-reply, publish-subscribe, pipeline and exclusive pair [core patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#toc26). Unfortunately it haven't current pascal/delphi binding. You can find many (non pascal) examples in [0MQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)

Comment: the question was specific about delphi